# Atom feed generatore

Tags: php, laravel, rss, laravel-5

im creating a atom feed, but i believe mayb there is a issue, my feed is all splashed up on the screen, is not formatting, in firefox works well, but chrome isnt, i already installed a chrome extension, but still the feed isnt being format, maybe is something missing.

My code:

rss controller:

public function index()
    {

```
   $data['posts'] = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(10)->get();


    return response()->view('feed.rss', $data, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8');

}
```

view:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';?>


<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title>title</title>
    <subtitle>some subtitle</subtitle>
    <link href="http://domain/feed"/>

    <updated>{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->toATOMString() }}</updated>
    <author>
        <name>Roger a</name>
    </author>

    <id></id>

    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <entry>
        <title> {{$post->title}}</title>
        <link>http://domainurl</link>
        <id></id>
        <updated>....</updated>
        <summary>{{$post->sub_title}}</summary>
    </entry>

    @endforeach

</feed>
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to be nicely formatted? It is an Atom feed. It is designed to be consumed by Feed Readers, not by Web Browsers.

Comment: but is being consumed by feed readers.,. thats why i install chrome plugin to check if is reading well...read the post